# nodeJs display on web browser

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, cmd, requirejs

Just want to display my node.js result on web browser..
is it possible?...

here's my code:

```
const testFolder = 'texts/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
})
```

when I try to run that code on cmd it works. The code gets all the .txt file on a specific directory.

here's the result:
[image]
then when i tried to load it on my browser the result goes like this
[image]

Im also planing to add all the result filename to database mysql once the node.js code fixed.. is that also possible?..

thank you.. this is my first time to create a node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the express router to accept `GET` request from your browser :

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const testFolder = 'texts/';
// To set your public directory and use relative url
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'your_public_dir'));

// When you access to localhost:8080, it will send GET '/' request
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
    });
});
```

Comment: do I have to install it?... I try using your code then I got error...
Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Comment: normally it's already installed, try to install it with npm to see if you still have the error

Comment: I tried to run it on with installed express and instal requiredJS.. still the same result.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas is right, express can achieve this. Just remember to install it using NPM, this can be done by executing following command under the directory where package.json is:

```
npm install --save express
```

however, you would also need to write into response of the server so it shows on website. So for example, using Express:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.write("whatever you want to display");
    res.end()
});
```